# Python print bytes without terminator

Tags: python, printing, hex, byte

I am trying to print shell code with python but it adds a `\x0a` terminator. Is there a way to print without the terminator?

```
# cat test.py 
print(b'\x41\x41\x41\x41')

# python test.py |xxd -g1
0000000: 41 41 41 41 0a                                   AAAA.

# python test.py | wc
  1       1       5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x0A is a newline (LF, \n) which Python adds automatically to print statements.

For Python 3, use `print(..., end="")`.

In Python 2, end the print statement with a comma like so:

```
print "abc",
```

However, Python will still try to print a newline when it exits. You may be better off using `sys.stdout.write()`.

Comment: Thanks. For python 2 could you give an example of this please? I've tried ending with a comma in a couple different way but I can't seem to get it right lol. I guess you can import the new print function though `from __future__ import print_function` and print will behave like python3

Comment: Apparently Py2 likes to print a newline when it exits. Try: `print "abc",`, `print "def"` - there will be no newline (the space comes from the second print). I corrected my answer.

Comment: (In general, print in Python 2 is meant for human consumption - I would guess that it's trying to keep your terminal consistent (print the prompt at the start of the line) by ending with a newline)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah `sys.stdout.write()` is the way to go for printing the hex bytes without a newline byte.